# Why does a perfectly fine free on a string cause "free(): invalid next size"?

Tags: c, gcc, free, glibc

## BAD QUESTION

The code suddenly works as it should. I can't recall  having changed the code at all from when it crashed to now, other than adding some `printf`s for debugging. I just removed the comment from `free(c);` and now it works.

So please remove this question

---

The free on line 48 is the one in question. Once I remove it, my program runs fine, but with memory leakage of course. The string is `malloc`ed, filled by `sprintf` and attempted freed, but unsuccessfully.

I've pastebinned the function by demand
[int extcommand(char** param)](http://pastebin.com/njWJEVru)

The free line causes the following carnage:

```
*** glibc detected *** ./bin/tomashell: free(): invalid next size (fast): 0x094e7030 ***
======= Backtrace: =========
/lib/i686/cmov/libc.so.6(+0x6b281)[0xb7656281]
/lib/i686/cmov/libc.so.6(+0x6cad8)[0xb7657ad8]
/lib/i686/cmov/libc.so.6(cfree+0x6d)[0xb765abbd]
./bin/tomashell[0x8048ffb]
./bin/tomashell[0x8048e28]
./bin/tomashell[0x8048c37]
/lib/i686/cmov/libc.so.6(__libc_start_main+0xe6)[0xb7601c76]
./bin/tomashell[0x8048751]
======= Memory map: ========
08048000-0804a000 r-xp 00000000 08:01 5578979    /root/Dropbox/UIO/INF1060/hjemmeeksamen-1/tomashell/bin/tomashell
0804a000-0804b000 rw-p 00001000 08:01 5578979    /root/Dropbox/UIO/INF1060/hjemmeeksamen-1/tomashell/bin/tomashell
094e7000-09508000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0          [heap]
b7400000-b7421000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0
b7421000-b7500000 ---p 00000000 00:00 0
b75c5000-b75e2000 r-xp 00000000 08:01 1843203    /lib/libgcc_s.so.1
b75e2000-b75e3000 rw-p 0001c000 08:01 1843203    /lib/libgcc_s.so.1
b75ea000-b75eb000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0
b75eb000-b772b000 r-xp 00000000 08:01 1860235    /lib/i686/cmov/libc-2.11.2.so
b772b000-b772d000 r--p 0013f000 08:01 1860235    /lib/i686/cmov/libc-2.11.2.so
b772d000-b772e000 rw-p 00141000 08:01 1860235    /lib/i686/cmov/libc-2.11.2.so
b772e000-b7731000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0
b7736000-b773a000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0
b773a000-b773b000 r-xp 00000000 00:00 0          [vdso]
b773b000-b7756000 r-xp 00000000 08:01 1843225    /lib/ld-2.11.2.so
b7756000-b7757000 r--p 0001a000 08:01 1843225    /lib/ld-2.11.2.so
b7757000-b7758000 rw-p 0001b000 08:01 1843225    /lib/ld-2.11.2.so
bf9f8000-bfa0d000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0          [stack]
Aborted
```

**Why can't I free my string?**

Here is some extra information

```
root@chu:~/sc/tomashell# gcc --version
gcc (Debian 4.4.5-8) 4.4.5
Copyright (C) 2010 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
This is free software; see the source for copying conditions.  There is NO
warranty; not even for MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.

root@chu:~/sc/tomashell# uname -a
Linux chu 2.6.32-5-686 #1 SMP Mon Jun 13 04:13:06 UTC 2011 i686 GNU/Linux
root@chu:~/sc/tomashell#
```

Comment: You forgot to show us the part where `cmdlen` gets assigned.

Comment: Sorry, I've pastebinned the entire function now

Comment: If the problem mysteriously went away, it's likely that you have some undefined behavior somewhere, and that your program is now "working" only by blind luck.  (I say this without actually having looked at the code.)

Comment: If the problem goes away, and you don't know why, you are now in a far worse position than you were before.

Comment: Well yes, but I've confirmed that all the numbers are correct, the size of the malloc, the size of all the strings, the pointer that gets freed etc. Isn't it possible that my previous errors were due to me forgetting to save a file or something?

Comment: @Codemonkey, it's more likely that you have an error _somewhere else_ that you managed to make visible. Hiding this is a Bad Thing - it'll probably come back later, just when you can least afford for it to do so. Run valgrind on your program :)

Comment: @bdonlan, Does Valgrind run the proper tests by default? When I run it on my program it just tells me I have no memory leaks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, the obvious answer is that the `sprintf` is printing more characters than there is allocated space, so that some info on the end of the block (containing bookkeeping info for the memory manager) is being overwritten. Without examining the whole program, there are too many uncertainties here for us to diagnose it perfectly. For example, we don't know what `param` points to, and how you guarantee it's not too long. You could use `snprintf` to do this more safely.

Comment: Sorry, I've pastebinned the entire function now

Answer (score 3):

You have what is known as 'heap corruption'. This is when you go and corrupt (ie, change) some memory that doesn't belong to you - maybe you wrote before the block `malloc` gave you, or maybe after the end of such a block, maybe you used a block after you freed it, etc.

The thing about heap corruption is you don't always crash at the very moment that you screw up. Often the corruption goes unnoticed for a while; your program may even terminate before the heap manager notices. But once it does, your program may crash at a point *completely unrelated to the original error*. It's the kind of spooky action-at-a-distance that Einstein would have hated.

The easiest way to track down this sort of thing is to run your program in [valgrind](http://valgrind.org/); valgrind identifies a number of common heap corruptions and will report stacktraces that point at the actual moment in which the corruption occurred. You can then go and fix the root cause of the error.